# adding tooltip to d3js focus chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

I have created a chart using this example [Sample](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367)
 and added a tooltip.

But in the chart the tool tip comes like this. In a really different way. The tooltip i tried was d3-tip library.

This is not a bar-chart. It is a line chart but it behave like this when i enable the tool tip.

[image]

This is my code. Still i could not find the issue why it is happening.

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    margin2 = {top: 220, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 300 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;

    var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"),
    xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

    var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", brushed);

    var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.timeStamp); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.inFlightRequestCount); });

    var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function(d) {
        return "<strong>Flight Request Count:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.inFlightRequestCount +
        "</span> <strong>Time:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + new Date(d.timeStamp) + "</span>";
    })

    var line2 = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function(d) { return x2(d.timeStamp); })
    .y(function(d) { return y2(d.inFlightRequestCount); });

    var svg = d3.select("#rowTable1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

    svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

    var focus = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "context")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");


    svg.call(tip);

    var data = [{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417228979,"inFlightRequestCount":22.0},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417288983,"inFlightRequestCount":32.5},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417348980,"inFlightRequestCount":42.5},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417408983,"inFlightRequestCount":52.5},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417468981,"inFlightRequestCount":62.0},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417528982,"inFlightRequestCount":66.66666666666667},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417588983,"inFlightRequestCount":48.75},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417648983,"inFlightRequestCount":41.25},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417708980,"inFlightRequestCount":55.0},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417768983,"inFlightRequestCount":90.0},{"clusterId":"cartridge-group-app.my-tomcat.tomcat.domain","timeStamp":1437417828981,"inFlightRequestCount":90.0}];

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timeStamp; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.inFlightRequestCount; })]);


    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timeStamp; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.inFlightRequestCount; })]);
    x2.domain(x.domain());
    y2.domain(y.domain());

    focus.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

    focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

    focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

    context.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line2);

    context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
    .call(xAxis2);

    context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("y", -6)
    .attr("height", height2 + 7);

    svg.selectAll(".line2")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.timeStamp); })
    .attr("width", 1)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.inFlightRequestCount); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.inFlightRequestCount); })
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide)


    function brushed() {
      x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
      focus.select(".line").attr("d", line);
      focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  }

  function type(d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.timeStamp);
      d.price = +d.inFlightRequestCount;
      return d;
  }
```

Can anyone please help me to find this issue.Any help will be highly appreciated.

This is what i expect to do.(NOTE : this is photoshopped.) [image]

Comment: How do you want it to appear?

Comment: i want it to apear on the edges of the graph.even if i focus in to the graph it shud be like that. like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__ctr09ZdKJbEdfaTZ3QXFuTjg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You mean to say near the y-axis?? Because I can't find a difference between what is posted in question and what is posted in google drivce

Comment: the way i need the graph is this.but the data want overlap.it draws as lines in this chart. this is what i expect to do. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__ctr09ZdKJV2p5bzF3MVFDTzQ/view?usp=sharing (NOTE : this is a photoshopped example of my expectation.)